# UVA 10474 - “Where is the marble?”

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, programming-challenge

I have been solving the problem from [UVA 10474](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=1415&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+14660930). In this problem, there will be marbles with numbers written on them. For example suppose five marbles with numbers 50 , 43, 43, 43, 2, 90, 44. There will be several query with number and position has to be told in a sorted sequence. For example after sorting these looks like : 2,43,43,43,44,50,90. Now, query for 43 will give output : 43 fond at 2 and query for -3 will output "-3 not found".

Can you please review it and provide me with feedback?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

void printMarbelPositionIfFound()
{
    int numMarbles, numQueries, aMarble, case1;
    std::vector<int>marbles;

    case1 = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &numMarbles, &numQueries);
        if(0 == numMarbles && 0 == numQueries)return;

        case1++;

        for(int i=0; i<numMarbles; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &aMarble);
            marbles.push_back(aMarble);
        }

        std::sort(marbles.begin(), marbles.end());
        std::cout<<"CASE#"<<" "<<case1<<":"<<"\n";
        for(int i=0; i<numQueries; i++)
        {

            scanf("%d", &aMarble);

            std::vector<int>::const_iterator itr = std::lower_bound(marbles.begin(), marbles.end(),aMarble);
            if(*itr == aMarble)
            {
                std::cout<<aMarble<<" found at "<<itr - marbles.begin() + 1<<'\n';
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout<<aMarble<<" not found"<<'\n';
            }
        }

        marbles.clear();
    }
}

int main()
{
    printMarbelPositionIfFound();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since nothing in the problem description forbids it, you could probably get better results using std::find found in the <algorithm> header

Comment: Thanks @tinstaafl . Didn't know about std::find(). I have just checked it. Its time complexity is at most O(n) while std::lower_bound has complexity at most O(lgn). So, I think it will be inefficient compared to std::lower_bound().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing C with C++. I know these contests like speed, but it is usually unnecessary.

**1. Prefer streams over `scanf`.**

This means you can change this code:

```
    scanf("%d %d", &numMarbles, &numQueries);
```

Into this:

```
    std::cin >> numMarbles >> numQueries ;
```

**2. Use the C++11 `auto` keyword when possible.**

You have a C++11 tag, so I assume you have C++11 available.
You can change this:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator itr = std::lower_bound(marbles.begin(), marbles.end(),aMarble);
```

To this:

```
auto itr = std::lower_bound(marbles.begin(), marbles.end(),aMarble);
```

**3. Make sure the iterator does not point past the end when you dereference it.**

In this line: `if(*itr == aMarble)`, you dereference the iterator. If `aMarble` is not in `marbles`, then `std::lower_bound()` will return `marbles.end()`. It is undefined behavior to dereference `marbles.end()`. Always check for this condition.

So change this line:

```
if(*itr == aMarble)
```

To this:

```
if (iter != marbles.end () && *itr == aMarble)
```

**4. Prefer pre-increment over post-increment.**

You have:

```
case1++;
```

In the case an `int`, it doesn't really matter. Your compiler will optimize this correctly. But if you had a complicated object, then you would be creating an unnecessary copy here. So:

```
++case1;
```

Would be a better habit to get into.

**5. Encapsulate input and output with an Object.**

You could create an object that represents a single unit of input. Something like this:

```
struct Input
{
    int nMarbles ;
    int nQueries ;
    static int caseNumber ;

    std::vector <int> marbles ;
    std::vector <int> queries ;

    Input () ;
    void Clear () ;

    friend auto operator>> (std::istream &is, Input &input) -> std::istream& ;
    friend auto operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Input &input) -> std::ostream& ;
};
```

Then you could implement the member and friend functions like this:

```
int Input::caseNumber = 0 ;

Input::Input () : nMarbles (), nQueries ()
{
} 

void Input::Clear ()
{
    nMarbles = 0 ;
    nQueries = 0 ;
    marbles.clear () ;
    queries.clear () ;
}

auto operator>> (std::istream& is, Input &input) -> std::istream&
{
    ++Input::caseNumber ;

    is >> input.nMarbles >> input.nQueries ;
        
    if (input.nMarbles == 0 && input.nQueries == 0) {
        is.setstate (std::ios::failbit) ;
        return is ;
    }

    auto begin = std::istream_iterator <int> (is) ;
    std::copy_n (begin, input.nMarbles, std::back_inserter (input.marbles)) ;
    
    begin = std::istream_iterator <int> (is) ;
    std::copy_n (begin, input.nQueries, std::back_inserter (input.queries)) ;

    return is ;
}

auto operator<< (std::ostream &os, Input &input) -> std::ostream&
{
    os << "CASE# " << Input::caseNumber << ":" "\n" ;

    auto &marbles = input.marbles ;

    std::sort (std::begin (marbles), std::end (marbles)) ;
    
    for (int query : input.queries) {
        auto iter = std::lower_bound (std::begin (marbles), std::end (marbles), query) ;

        if (iter != std::end (marbles) && *iter == query) {
            os << query << " found at " << (std::distance (std::begin (marbles), iter) + 1) << "\n" ;
        }

        else {
            os << query << " not found" "\n" ;
        }
    }

    return os ;
}
```

Then your driver would look like this:

```
int main ()
{
    Input input ;

    while (std::cin >> input) {
        std::cout << input ;
        input.Clear () ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

With the above code, I got an accepted answer with a runtime of 0.212 units on your website. So streams are more than fast enough for this particular challenge.